# Why did the English people switch from the Celtic language to Old English?

Tags: history, old-english

There is a widely held theory that when the Romans left England in the 5th century AD the island was defenceless against Anglo-Saxon invading armies. In the south and east the Britons were defeated in battle and the Anglo-Saxons established their own kingdoms. They brought their  Germanic languages with them -Old English- which became dominant in the new kingdoms and ultimately in Britain as a whole. Only Wales and Cornwall were able to retain their Celtic language and culture.

However, a recent history programme on the BBC disputes this theory. They claim there is no evidence of a border between Celtic and Anglo-Saxon speaking regions, nor of battles along such a border in the 5th century. Instead they claim that Wales and Cornwall were regions in the west that were involved in trade with France and Spain. Whereas the south and east of England had contacts around the North Sea with Belgium, Netherlands, Germany, Denmark and Norway. There was trade, and perhaps some migration of settlers, but certainly no conquest by invading Anglo-Saxon armies.

Assuming that the theory of the BBC is correct, why is it that the common people (farmers, fishermen, villagers) in the south and east of England stopped speaking the Celtic language of their ancestors and instead switched to Old English, the language of a relatively small group of newcomers?

Comment: Interesting question, but perhaps more suited to the History forum?

Comment: I think the theory you mention is a minority view but languages can change surprisingly quickly for all kinds of reasons. Nobody really knows why the Kingdom of Alba (Scotland) switched from Pictish to Gaelic - there's no evidence of conquest or large scale immigration. Although in England Celtic society had been weakened by the Romans, and the spread of Christianity might have been a factor. Maybe it's more a history question, certainly one historians have more chance of answering than linguists.

Comment: It depends how far to the West you go. The further you go the further you are removed from the dominant use of Old and Middle English. Cornish, Welsh, and Gaelic were all well established and widely spoken up until the early 18th century at which point Cornish disappeared with the increasing interaction between fishing and mining interests. Welsh and Gaelic survive.  Language follows trade as can be seen in the British and French empires.

Comment: The actual fact is that people -- even in Britain -- can learn and speak more than one language. Which one they speak in a given context is what changes, and that can change very fast. Language spread does not mean population spread; it's economic, not martial.  Also, a dialect you don't understand of a language you "know" is just another language you don't understand, so language family relations are quite vague to speakers.

Comment: While conquest is often cited as the reason for many language changes, commerce is also a big influence -- if you trade with a group frequently, you'll learn their language. And fashion is another reason -- when the Normans took over the British government, upperclass people adopted French words to emulate them, while commoners stuck with the Germanic words.

Comment: There is also a theory that when England started being settled by Anglo-Saxon speakers, the Anglo0Saxons were fishermen who lived on the coast, while the Celts were farmers and herders who lived inland.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about history, not language.

Comment: The reason for everything: Money.  With the arrival of reasonable transport links and an economy centred on the English speaking part of the British Isles, enabled by the stability of a unified kingdom, if you wanted to make money through trade, you spoke Old English, and then Middle English, and then Modern English.